# Is it valid to use grouped statements on their own?

Tags: php, syntax

I didn't think that this was valid PHP (I'm sure I tried this once years ago), but to my surprise it does run (although I've only tested on PHP 5.5.9):

```
<?php

$arr = [];

$arr[] = 'Hi.';

{
    $arr[] = '> Hi there.';
    $arr[] = '> What can I do for you?';
}

$arr[] = 'Nothing really.';

print_r($arr);
```

Outputs...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi.
    [1] => > Hi there.
    [2] => > What can I do for you?
    [3] => Nothing really.
)
```

The PHP manual refers to `{...}` as a group statement when [introducing control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php) - however, I can't find any mention of using them outside of this context. It does say "A statement-group is a statement by itself as well", but that seems a bit ambiguous.

Is this genuinely valid? If I use braces like this, can I expect my code to run in future versions? If a statement group is considered a statement by itself, should I expect it to have an affect line numbers and frames in exception stack traces?

Comment: Seems to work from php-5.4 and up http://3v4l.org/UKeY5

Comment: Of course it's valid... It's valid in JavaScript too. Probably many more languages.

Comment: Works in Java and C, too. The difference is that they don't introduce a new scope in either JavaScript or PHP, but they do in Java and C. So, they're pretty much useless in the former languages outside control structures.

Comment: It has absolutely no affect whatsoever on line numbers and stack traces, so there's no need to worry about it causing problems there

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a429bebd14f5130716f9c6492259d8f0bdd26b5

Comment: Wow. I've never seen it used before. Sounds like @NiettheDarkAbsol has seen it a thousand times though!

Comment: @Alex It's one of those things that I've *used* a thousand times, but never seen anyone else use. I use it so that I can fold my code in Notepad++ into logical groups for easier browsing. Similarly, I use `(..)` as delimiters in regex, used it a thousand times, nobody else seems to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this genuinely valid?

Yes, since at least 4.3

> If I use braces like this, can I expect my code to run in future versions?

Until it's removed from the language, yes. Breaking changes happen very rarely.

> If a statement group is considered a statement by itself, should I expect it to have an affect line numbers and frames in exception stack traces?

Frames don't include group statements such as `if`, `while` and `for`, so I would expect: no. Why not try it out?

Comment: Actually, this works also on PHP 5.2.5, so I guess all of 5.2.x: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a429bebd14f5130716f9c6492259d8f0bdd26b5

Comment: I've tested exceptions on 5.5.9, and it doesn't seem to have any weird affects on the trace.